# Expected [ ] to be [ ] Jasmine, how to check empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Getting error while trying to check for empty array. I tried using:

Case 1: By initializing as an array

```
expect(fixture.componentInstance.dataSource).toBe([]);
```

Case 2: By initializing as an array

```
let expectedAry = new Array;
expect(fixture.componentInstance.dataSource).toBe(expectedAry);
```

Both the case have the same error:

```
Expected [  ] to be [  ].
```

Arrays can also be checked by their length, the following works fine

```
expect(fixture.componentInstance.dataSource.length).toEqual(0);
```

0 length is an option, but not sure if that is the right way to check whether an array is empty. Do we have a better option for checking whether an array is empty?

Comment: Use the `toEqual` expectation.

Comment: Exampe for jest:  expect(expected).toEqual([]) https://www.codegrepper.com/tpc/jest+expect+empty+array

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`toBe` doesn't check the contents of the array, it only checks if the references are the same.

`expect([1]).toBe([1])` will fail because the references are different.

You should use `toEqual`, which has some smarts to check the array contents as opposed to just doing a reference comparison.

Answer (score 30):

Use `toHaveSize` matcher:

```
expect(array).toHaveSize(0);
```

---

It's strongly recommended to use because the error messages you get with it are much better (e.g. `Error: Expected array to have size 0`)

Coming with `Jasmine 3.6`: [release docs](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/main/release_notes/3.6.0.md)

Answer (score 5):

Use .toHaveLength to check that an object has a .length property and it is set to a certain numeric value.

This is especially useful for checking arrays or strings size.

```
expect([1, 2, 3]).toHaveLength(3);
expect('abc').toHaveLength(3);
expect('').not.toHaveLength(5);
```

source https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavelengthnumber

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this -

```
expect(component.XYZ.length).toEqual(0);
```

Comment: Please have a look carefully, its not the same :)

Comment: I am talking about component.XYZ.length toEqual 0.

Comment: Alright, got it. I removed my comment. I still think you should explain in your answer what makes it different from the accepted one and why you think this is a better solution. Thanks. :)

Comment: some times it will throw error can not read length of undefined